# How do unsigned transactions propagate when network compromised?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

say if my application is relatively new and has lesser nodes can be prone to 51% attack.

**Example:**

Person A - 100BTC

Person B - 50BTC

Person C - 0BTC (Malicious user)

If person C somehow get control over the network creates the longest Chain & has blocks with invalid transactions i.e. A sent to C 80 BTC & B sent to C 50 BTC which is not really signed by A & B with there privateKey(invalid transactions created by C).

The question here is tough Network is compromised as the transactions are not singed by original owners will the `C` able to spend them ? is consensus gone for a toss here? if I miss the trick somewhere please do point.

Answer (score 0):

C cannot spend other's money, unless he could gain access other's private keys and sign transactions. Even if he try to, the block won't be considered as valid since transactions we'rent signed by the owners of the coin.

Answer (score 0):

The rules, known to all participants, say that a transaction must be properly-signed. These are the very same rules that say how many bitcoins a transaction transfers. So if a transaction is not properly-signed, it does *not* transfer any bitcoins.

Let me state this again: There are rules that allow you to determine how many bitcoins a transaction transfers. These very same rules say that a transaction must be properly-signed. Therefore, a transaction that is not properly-signed *does not* transfer any bitcoins.

Nodes do not trust each other in the bitcoin network. Every message sent is checked for validity and, if invalid, it has to be ignored because it doesn't mean anything. A transaction that is not properly signed isn't a transaction, it's just garbage. Nodes can send you all the garbage they want to, but you'll never process any of it because you *can't*. Your code simply doesn't have rules to make sense of garbage.

Answer (score -1):

I got my answer after detail research hope it makes sense.

Person C cannot spend A, B money. All he can do is reverse transactions and create a double spend situation and he can **erase** A, B transactions in the process of making a longest chain but cannot spend money from other wallets tough network is compromised because of private/public keys.